# How to create Splash screen for App developed by Adobe AIR using Android?

Tags: android, dynamic-splash-screen

In my application i am using `splash screen with time intervel` when app starts for few seconds like 5 or 6 seconds . this is the code am using

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(NativeSplash.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);               
    }
}, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Here i am facing weird problem while loading `MainActivity`( AppEntry code developed in FlashBuilder AIR ). while it's loading blank screen appearing before `MainActivity` comes to front.

Is it possible to keep splash screen while loading `MainActivity` instead of showing blank screen (with out time Interval) ?

I can show splash screen for few minutes but loading main activity takes time. That loading time varies device to device. so planning to make `splash screen independent on time.`

Comment: what exactly you are doing in main activity and why it's taking time explain clearly.. one solution when splash time over in main activity display a progress bar until it finishes background tasks..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making an `InitialLoading` activity or fragment that does all the loading and starts when the app is started. `InitialLoading` could have a layout that simply shows your splash screen and finishes when the loading is done.

Comment: Here loading means i am calling MainActivity (AppEntry develeloped in FlashBuilder AIR ) so i can't create a Init Loader with res.

Answer (score 0):

Put your all loading code of `MainActivity` in `AsyncTask`.... 
Show the Splash screen until loading finishes..

On post execute of Async Task, start new activity i.e. MainActivity.

Comment: Here loading means i am calling MainActivity (AppEntry develeloped in FlashBuilder AIR ) so i can't create a Init Loader with res.

Comment: IS your app developed in FlashBuilder??

Comment: Full application developed in Flash builder. i am facing problem when it's loading first time. it takes nearly 10 sec to get first screen in the app. so i am planning to keep splash screen through native (android).

Comment: run a thread for 10 second in sleep mode something like
 Thread t=new Thread(){ public void run() { try{ sleep(7000); } catch(Exception e){ } Intent i=new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class); startActivity(i); } }; t.start();

Comment: @iCodeAtAndroid Look at my code same thing i am doing now , i am looking for independent of splash screen..

Comment: If it is developed in Flash, it can handle ur issue easily by calling funtion on CreationComplete event.

Comment: Your plan to develop Splash in NATIVE is wrong.. Flash has that ability.. GO for that only

Comment: How to develop in android,? i have idea how to develop for ios, i am not sure about android. can you tell me what event i have to register for this. if you have any code please share with me. thx

Comment: Do you want in android or Flash?? I am telling about flash

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41609/discussion-between-sweetwisher-and-rajareddy-polamreddy)